# Invalid Column in a Oracle Pagination query?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm writing a Oracle SQL query for pagination, it works fine in sql developer but when I try to run through java application using Spring JDBC Template it throws

> SQLException: **Invalid column type**

Actual Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT a.*, rownum r__ 
    FROM ( 
       SELECT * 
       FROM Packet 
       ORDER BY packet_date_created DESC 
    ) a 
    WHERE rownum < ((pageNumber*pageSize)+1) 
)
WHERE r__ >= (((pageNumber-1)* pageSize)+1)
```

In Java:

```
MapSQlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSQlParameterSource ()
paramSource.addValue("pageNumber", pageNumber.intValue())
paramSource.addValue("pageSize", pageSize.intValue())

String sqlString = 
   "SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, rownum r__ FROM ( SELECT  FROM packet ORDER BY packet_date_created DESC ) a  " +
   "WHERE rownum < ((:pageNumber * :pageSize) + 1 )) " +
   "WHERE r__ >= (((:pageNumber-1) * :pageSize) + 1)";
List<PacketDTO> packetDTOList = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlString, paramSource, new PacketMapper());
```

Any suggestions around would be really appreciated.

Comment: The Java code listing that you've shared is incomplete, what is `paramSource` containing?

Comment: I've added..Please have a look

Comment: What is the table definition of your packet table?  Can you post the exception stack?  Can you post your PacketMapper code?

Comment: What version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Take a look at your mapper and be sure that all getXXXs that you use are supported by the driver.

Comment: having a column alias r__ is fine.  Oracle doesn't object. So the answer lies in the a.*, 
What is the DDL of table Packet  ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with special "__" characters of your alias for the rownum speudocolumn.  Try a different alias name for your rownum return column, or try including the {escape '_'} inclusion syntax.  I'd simply change the pseudocolumn alias myself.

Comment: Oracle is fine with r__ as a column alias. Try:
select r__
  from (    select rownum as r__
              from dual
        connect by rownum <= 10)

Answer (score 0):

Did you used `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` ?

like this...

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
 <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this query Oracle:

```
SELECT * 
       FROM Packet 
       ORDER BY packet_date_created DESC
OFFSET :v_offset ROWS FETCH NEXT :v_CountNextRows ROWS ONLY;
```

PS: It  works only in Oracle 12C.